# Comma not appearing in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic-text

I have a textbok called stateExplanation. I want to dynamically change the text inside the textbook. This is my ActionScript 3:

```
stateExplanation.text='Small portion of Pro and large portion of other, Both cease.';
```

and for some reason when I run the Fla file as a Swf, the comma after the word 'other' do not show up. If I change the comma to a '.', the '.' does show up. How do I get the comma to show up?

Note: I am using ActionScript 3 and Flash CS5 with Flash Player 10.

Comment: Are you embedding the font?

Comment: @Marcela ah, wow, I forgot to do that. It worked I embedded the font. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in the comments: the font needed to be embedded.